# I am getting this error in heroku => at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy my node js app to heroku and I am getting this error at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/". Most of the answers tell me to set the port value to process.env.PORT, I have done this multiple times but to no effect.

```
//app.js
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_STRING);
    console.log("db connected");
    app.listen(port, () =>
      console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`)
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();
```

```
//package.json
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
"engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  }
```

```
//Procfile
web : node app.js
```

This is my code related to heroku deployment ...can you find any issues ? I think I am doing everything right.

Comment: Hey, i think we are on the same page, i've also been fighting this issue, did you manage to find a solution ?

Comment: I just realised your colon in your Procfile is not next to 'web'.

Maybe instead of 
`web : app.js`

Put 
``web: node.js``